# Unit Testing Async Controller: Exception on Url.Link()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, nunit, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to unit test a async controller. Ive done this many times before but never called the `Url.Link()`method in order to generate the Location Header.

Heres my demo code.

### Controller

```
public class DemoController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DemoRequestPost(string someRequest)
    {
        // do something await ...
        var id = 1;
        // generate url for location header (here the problem occurrs)
        var url = Url.Link("DemoRequestGet", new {id = id});
        return Created(url, id);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("demo/{id}", Name = "DemoRequestGet")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DemoRequestGet(int id)
    {
        // return something
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

### Test

```
[TestFixture]
public class DemoControllerTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task CreateFromDraftShouldSucceed()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = "Hello World";
        var controller = new DemoController();
        var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        // ensure attribte routing is setup
        httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        httpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized();
        controller.Configuration = httpConfiguration;
        // Act
        var result = await controller.DemoRequestPost(request);
        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(result, 1);
    }
}
```

I am receiving

> at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ExceptionHelper.Rethrow(Exception exception)
>   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncInvocationRegion.AsyncTaskInvocationRegion.WaitForPendingOperationsToComplete(Object invocationResult)
>   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunAsyncTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)

Comment: You should `await` the result. Try `var result = await controller.DemoRequestPost(request);`

Comment: Sorry,  it was a mistake in my sample code. The same Exception occurs if I await the result.

Comment: What is the exception that is being thrown and what is the message on the exception? Or is NUnit not reporting the full exception info. If so, that is a bug, please report it at https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues. If you are not getting the exception, try wrapping in a try/catch to catch the exception and examine it in the debugger. Hopefully that will tell you why it is failing.

Comment: Nunit does not report the exception. The test simply failed and even debugging the test does not help. Besides that I guess I think the problem has to do with the missing MapHttpAttributeRoutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the *Testing Link Generation* in [Unit Testing Controllers in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api)

> The UrlHelper class needs the request URL and route data, so the test
>   has to set values for these.

You are not setting those in your example hence your error.

Here is one of their examples

```
[TestMethod]
public void PostSetsLocationHeader()
{
    // Arrange
    ProductsController controller = new ProductsController(repository);

    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage { 
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/products") 
    };
    controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
    controller.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi", 
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    controller.RequestContext.RouteData = new HttpRouteData(
        route: new HttpRoute(),
        values: new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "products" } });

    // Act
    Product product = new Product() { Id = 42, Name = "Product1" };
    var response = controller.Post(product);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("http://localhost/api/products/42", response.Headers.Location.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

based on that article you can do something like this which is mocking the `UrlHelper` using Moq.

```
[TestClass]
public class DemoControllerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task CreateFromDraftShouldSucceed() {
        // This version uses a mock UrlHelper.

        // Arrange
        var controller = new DemoController();
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        string locationUrl = "http://localhost/api/demo/1";

        // Create the mock and set up the Link method, which is used to create the Location header.
        // The mock version returns a fixed string.
        var mockUrlHelper = new Mock<UrlHelper>();
        mockUrlHelper.Setup(x => x.Link(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(locationUrl);
        controller.Url = mockUrlHelper.Object;

        // Act
        var request = "Hello World";
        var result = await controller.DemoRequestPost(request);
        var response = await result.ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(locationUrl, response.Headers.Location.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad, do you know a solution like the first one but with Attribute Routing ?

Comment: @dknaack, can you elaborate? I don't understand what you mean? Attribute routing would only matter for integration test not unit test. However you can still call mapping extension on the `HttpConfiguration` when arranging the test

Comment: i would like to test the location header url. In order to do that i need the Url Helper to work probably. I can call HttpConfiguration MapHttpAttributeRoutes which works well. But the Url Helper does not generate a url (null).

Comment: Check the link I provided. they have examples of how to configure the UrlHelper. it needs a valid request.

Comment: Ive checked the link. But the article does not cover AttributeRoutes.

Comment: the route config is the same. attribute routing adds those routes to the route table.

Comment: ill check that out again later. Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 0):

@dknaack  For your controller test, you probably don't need this line of code:

```
    var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    httpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized();
    controller.Configuration = httpConfiguration;
```